# Bash Command to send Email

Tags: bash, sendmail

I have a file which contains a list of email addresses.  I would like to send out emails to this list via a bash command.  If possible, have the command check for duplicates and not send the email to a duplicate email.

Sample File Input:

```
  azzeddinetata@gmail.com
  testemail@gmail.com
  testsecond@gmail.com
  azzeddinetata@gmail.com
```

So in this example `azzeddinetata@gmail.com` should not receive a duplicate email.  Does anyone have any Bash commands to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this with your file :

```
mail -s subject "$(sed '/^$/d;s/ *//g' file.txt | sort -u | paste -sd ",")" <<EOF
message here
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mail -s "Subject" $(sort -u recipients-file) <<<"msg"
```